# What is the correct set of events for a continuous integration workflow with github actions?

Tags: github-actions

I'm using Github actions to run automated tests on every pull request. However, I don't know what is the correct set of events that I should be using. I've seen many variations of this, but I don't know which one is the proper one.

A) Only the pull_request event

```
on: [ pull_request ]
```

B) Only the push event

```
on: [ push ]
```

C) Both push and pull_request event

```
on:
    push:
        branches: [ master ]
    pull_request:
        branches: [ master ]
```

I started trying option (A), with only the pull_request event. However, that appears to be [incompatible with caching dependencies](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/310#issuecomment-628883421). Each pull request starts with an empty cache; the cache does not carry over to the next pull request.

I then tried to switch to option (B), with only the push event. The automated tests appear to run correctly for pull requests that are entirely inside my repository. However, if someone opens a pull request from an external fork, the status ends up stuck as `"Expected — Waiting for status to be reported"`. I don't know if this is expected behavior, because when I googled for that message I got [very few hits](https://github.community/t/github-actions-pull-requests-always-include-some-outdated-checks/16157/1) which I don't believe are related to my problem. (I'm not sure, this Github actions stuff is completely baffling.)

Finally, I tried switching to option (C) with both the push event and the pull event, as suggested in the [Github starter workflows](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/tree/main/ci). However, when I do this every the CI runs twice for every pull request. Once before it is merged and another time after it is merged. This seems terribly redundant and wasteful; I'd prefer if my test scripts only had to run once.

At the end, I'm terribly confused. Option (B) does what I want unless a fork is involved, in which case it fails miserably. Option (C) seems to be the default that Github recommends, but it runs the automated tests twice instead of only once. That can't possibly be right! What is the correct approach here?